# VS.NET - Multiple Find All References Result Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, find, reference

Visual Studio has a "Find All References" tool that is great in navigating the codebase to find out where a function is called or where a variable is used. When navigating a large code base, I tend to do find all references multiple times to find the top level of where a function is called.

Imagine we have the following:

A1() calls B1(), B1() calls C()

A2() calls B2(), B2() calls C()

My problem:

If I do find all references on C(), I find both B1() and B2(), which is great.

Now, I try to find out where B1() is called. I find A1() calls B1(). Great!

However, I run into an issue when I want to back track and find out what calls B2(), but I lost track of B2()! By default, VS.NET only has window for the "Find All References" result. Since I found all references for B1() just now, I lost track of where C() was called. I now have to find all references to C(), and then find all references to B2(). I'm working in a large code base, and finding all references can easily take more than a minute for a function. It would be nice if I could save the results of a search, and future find all references would open a new window instead of overwriting the existing search.

Is there a setting in VS.NET 2008 or a free addon that would allow me to have multiple "Find All References" windows?

On a related note, VS.NET has 2 Find result windows for searching for text. Is there a way to have more?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but apparently you can persist a results tab and get new results in a new tab, by using the "Keep Results" button at the panel's header (VS2017).

Comment: Still true for VS2022. Thanks for your answer ! There is indeed a "Keep result" button on the top of the result window, that tell Visual Studio to open to not overwrite / keep the current result set if there is a subsequent search. Even if it's an old question, it would be nice if someone can flag your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about studio, but [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this for you.  It will keep track of all your previous searches when you use the "Find Usages" function.  You also have some good flexibility for hte scope of hte search (Current File, Project, Solution, etc), as well as options for searching (usages of base types, etc).

They do have a free trial, so see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful trick is Ctrl+K+K (setting a bookmark) or Ctrl+K+N (traverse to next bookmark).  These get stored in the *.suo (user file) for Visual Studio.  This is also useful if you're searching large code bases and you get a million file tabs in Visual Studio.  If you keep the bookmark of where you're actually coding, you can flip back to that file tab in a blink of an eye.