# Keep previous "find all references" results

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I wonder, whether there is any way NOT to clear previous find all references results when making a next search?

If I do "find all references" once, the results will appear in "find symbol results window". I am working with a large solution, and if I do "Resolve results" it may take up to several minutes for the results to be resolved. And when I do the next "find all references", previous results will just disappear. Is there any way to keep them - just collapse - and add a new results below and so on... Anyway there is a "clear all" capability to clear the window...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050565/vs-net-multiple-find-all-references-result-windows except for the visual studio version(2008/2012), so in case no one come up with a better answer here for 2012 at least that one suggest some solutions that might still be useful.

Comment: This is not really as duplicate as this feature has changed with VS 2012.  Prior to 2012 two result tabs were available, providing a partial solution.

Answer (score 15):

In the new [Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5), our revised Find All References window supports this. Press the padlock icon/button (tooltip “Lock Results”) in the Find All References window’s toolbar, and Visual Studio will locks the results in that window, so that the next Find All References call you make will create a new Tool Window for the results. You can place the new tool window side by side with the previous result set if you wish. We’re improving labelling of this button in later releases.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, this button is called "Keep Results" and has a padlock icon as well.

Comment: OMG, I lived 2 years without knowing this button? I thought it was a bug with VS2017 as it never happened to me with VS2015... However, I want the button to stay ON all the time... I lose my results all the time and it is quite annoying.